# How to check whether a web page can be loaded in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I'm trying a accomplish a simple task. I want to be able to detect if a website can be loaded into iframe. If it can't be loaded, i want to load an alternative page.

For example:

```
$website = google.com 
$alternative = facebook.com 

<iframe id="myframe" scrolling="no" src="<?php echo $website; ?>"></iframe>
```

i want to be able to detect if the website (google.com) can be loaded into an iframe before i load it. Should in case, the website cant be loaded, i want to load the alternative (facebook.com) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample PHP code snippet for doing this kind of check.

```
function isIframeDisabled($src){
try{
    $headers = get_headers($src, 1);
    $headers = array_change_key_case($headers, CASE_LOWER);
    // Check Content-Security-Policy
    if(isset($headers[strtolower('Content-Security-Policy')])){
        return true;
    }
    // Check X-Frame-Options
    if(isset($headers[strtolower('X-Frame-Options')] &&
       (strtoupper($headers['X-Frame-Options']) == 'DENY' ||
        strtoupper($headers['X-Frame-Options']) == 'SAMEORIGIN')
    ){
        return true;
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // Ignore error
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: I have changed the answer check if that works.